# PHP which component for laravel with prolog

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, prolog

I would like to ask you if there is any component that I can use to connect laravel and prolog

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said which prolog supplier you wish to connect to, but swi-prolog comes with an [http server package](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/http.html), which handles regular http GET and POST requests from any http client.

It is possible to call swi prolog from the console from php, but http is much, much faster, as you're not shelling out to a console each time.

I don't know anything about Laravel, but a quick search shows it natively supports http via 'routes', so it should be possible in theory.

I have also successfully called swi prolog server from a php curl client. Laravel seems to have support for curl, so that be another way to initiate the http client GET/POST request.

Answer (score 0):

There is the abandoned https://packagist.org/packages/prologue/phpconsole for Laravel 4, or it's replacement https://packagist.org/packages/phpconsole/phpconsole that you might consider.